# Is my function to calculate the Manhattan Distance in MATLAB correct?

Tags: matlab

I'm using the A* search algorithm on two different heuristics. I've already done one of them and now I need to implement and use another one. I want to use the Manhattan Distance and I have a definition for it, so how the heuristic for it should be calculated, but I am not sure if it is correct. Everything compiles fine without errors etc.

My code:

```
function dist = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)
   dist = abs((x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2));
```

It seems correct to me but i'd just like to make sure.

When I run it, the heuristic value starts off big and as more nodes are explored and the closer it is to the target location, the heuristic gets smaller until it hits 0, which i'm assuming is what is supposed to happen.

Comment: You need to take the absolute value of each term, `abs(x1-x2) + abs(y1-y2)`. An x distance of `2` and y distance of `-2` should be 4, not 0.

Comment: There's the [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) function (Statistics Toolbox) which can do that for you

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark what do you mean by out sourcing my testing?

Comment: @beaker Makes sense. I've changed it to dist = abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1- y2);